# Paid and Free Version in seperate git branches

Tags: version-control, git, android

How do I manage and update two different app versions, which are with and without advertisements, but are otherwise identical, using git. Up to this point in development, I've only needed to maintain one branch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try to utilize version control for this, but I **recommend against it**.

Such a requirement is much easier to manage by maintaining only one "version" or "branch" of the application, when you add a compile-time [feature toggle](https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html) for enabling or disabling advertisements. If you like, you can also modify your build process to create always both variants of the application.

Comment: I agree. There's no real point to keeping two different source control branches/repos for something which is easily toggled.